# How to prevent the changing of a variable value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, static, final

Is there a way to declare a static of final value in javascript so that it cannot be altered by a 3rd party?

What I have is a article sharing application, with free users being ad supported.
What I wish to do is prevent the free users from altering the innerHTML content by altering the storage variable for the content.

What I have at this moment is a timer that reloads the innerHTML of the article on user website every 5 seconds and I'm storing the value for the reload in a variable.

However, if a genius using jsbeatify explores which variable holds the key to removing the ad and alters that, we lose revenue and exposure of our products.

How to prevent the altering of the internal variable?

---

### UPDATE

This is the end result of what I came up with:

http://jsfiddle.net/PgdYP/1/

```
<div id="specialdiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="try to change the function i to do something different" onclick="t.i = function(){alert(data.secret);}"><BR>
<input type="button" value="set function to null out of spite" onclick="t=null;">
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    e = function(){var data = { };
    Object.defineProperty(data, 'secret', {
       value: "Hello world!",
       writable : false,
       enumerable : true,
       configurable : false
       });this.z=function(){window.setTimeout("try{document.getElementById('specialdiv').innerHTML =   '"+data.secret+"';t.i.z();}catch(err) {document.body.innerHTML=err;}",5000);}}
        g = function(){};
        g.prototype = new e();e=null;window.t = {}
        Object.defineProperty(window.t, 'i', {
        value: new g(),
        writable : false,
        enumerable : false,
        configurable : false });g = null;
        window.t = Object.freeze(window.t); t = Object.seal(window.t);
        t.i.z();
    </script>
```

This will be presented in packed format, just to make it harder just to copy the code out of the source.
This way the effort to simply copy and paste the code out will be maximized and will be very hard to automate.

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: what was the name of the site you were working on again?

Comment: You should not care about the very few users that are capable of doing that, there is no way to control the page after it is loaded in users' browsers

Comment: the **const** keyword?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Constants

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is. At least for *object properties*, ES5 gave us the possiblity to alter the *property descriptor* flags by hand. So we can do that like

```
var data = { };

Object.defineProperty(data, 'secret', {
    value: 42,
    writable : false,
    enumerable : true,
    configurable : false
});
```

That way, we created a property `secret` with the value `42` within `data`, which cannot get modfied nor deleted.

The caveat here is, that the *genius* (like you called it) will also be able to spot this code and just modify that, to again be able to change the content if he wishes to. You just **can't** create a secured front-end javascript in that way. The code will always be available as plain-text for everybody.

---

To make this more complete, you can also create an object and `freeze` it at some point, using [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) and/or [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) to shutdown the option for *enumerating*, *deleting* and *modifying* on properties of an object.

**But again the word of caution**: This is intended to affect your own code or foreign code, to prevent modifications by accident or on purpose at run time. There is no way to stop a developer since he can simply *halt* the execution of your script, before this even can take affect.

Comment: @michael-dibbets Just to make things clear even further. You can't protect *anything*. Companies spend millions in security systems that get pwned some months after that. You won't just code the next big anti-vulnerable thing... in any way...

Comment: The reason is I want it unmodifyable on load and after that by javascript code.
I know that it's impossible to nail everything shut, but I want it to make it as hard as possible to alter the script output when it's on their site.
There is this treshhold for anyone who wishes to "cheat" between effort and result. This way I raise the bar another notch. Thank you.

Comment: +1 for the phrase "There is no way to stop a developer..." !

Comment: Note: If your defined property value is not a primitive datatype but an object, it can be modified (just not re-assigned).

Answer (score 2):

try the [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Constants) keyword. it should create an immutable variable.

Comment: interesting..., but I don't think IE implements this

Comment: @Ramesh you mean Google Chrome? http://caniuse.com/#feat=const

Comment: @jartaud - Ah I did not realise chrome is implementing this partially. But when I wrote the comment in 2012 IE 10 was the last stable release and it was also not supporting const :)

Comment: @Ramesh ikr? the black sheep is winning this one. :D

Comment: `const` does **not** make a variable immutable. `const a = []; a.push(1);` works. It just prevents the variable from being re-declared or re-assigned.

Comment: excepting objects